# C++ UpDown Control buddy how to set Value instead of WM_SETTEXT

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have a couple of small issues with an UpDown control

This is Using VS2015 with C++, WinApi without MFC

1. I can only seem to be able to set the text of an UpDown control 
   using

```
 SendMessage(hwndUpDnEdtBdy, WM_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)1, (LPARAM)(std::to_string(number).c_str()));
```

The problem that this causes, is when the control is at a value, like 10, and I set the text to a specific number, like 100. Next time I click on the +- of up-down control it changes to +-1 of the last numeric value that was there, which was 10.

How can I set the value of the Up Down control instead of the text?

And to answer why I need to do this: I have a second controller, trackbar, which works simultaneously with the up-down control.

2. When I use the WM_SETTEXT int he function above, I cannot set negative numbers, when I enter `-` it automatically creates a new line between - and the number. I have to set text to something like "n10" for it to be "-10", which is bad for user interface.

Yes, I have ES_MULTILINE enabled on the UpDown control buddy. I needed this so I can detect Enter being pressed once the number is typed in

```
HWND control = GetFocus();
switch (message)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
       if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_UPDATE && control == hwndUpDnEdtBdy)
       {
          char txt[6];
          GetWindowText(hwndUpDnEdtBdy, txt, sizeof(txt));
          if (CheckEnter(txt, sizeof(txt)))
          {
           //...Do Operation Here
          }
       }
}
    ...
bool CheckEnter(char* text, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (text[i] == '\r')
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

And Yes I tried using IDOK and it didn't work, 
my control class is subclassed as well.

Comment: Turn off `ES_MULTILINE` and make sure `ES_NUMBER` is set, and see if that fixes your problem. If it does you know up/down controls are not meant to work with multiline text fields.

Comment: Turning on `ES_MULTILINE` is the wrong way to detect the enter key.

Comment: OK I changed ES_MULTILINE to ES_NUMBER  and I tried the following code: `case WM_KEYDOWN:
  if (HIWORD(wParam) == VK_RETURN && control == hwndUpDnEdtBdy)`
       This still did not work, nothing happened when I entered a number and pressed enter,

Comment: Also, I cannot seem to enter negative numbers or decimals, eventhough the control range is set -100, 100

Comment: `ES_NUMBER` does not allow negatives, yes. For the up-down control, you need to set the value in the up-down control, not the buddy. And for negative numbers, you have to stop the up-down control from taking a `-` by itself and parsing that incorrectly. [This is the code I have for it](https://github.com/andlabs/libui/blob/master/windows/spinbox.cpp), you'll have to go by the function names to see what's going on. I'm not sure if my approach is correct or not (if it works by accident)... is it? (Open question. I only now see I forgot to set the `lResult` on `WM_COMMAND`; will fix later.)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I set the value of the Up Down control instead of the text?

Send it a [`UDM_SETPOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759955.aspx) or [`UDM_SETPOS32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759958.aspx) message.  The value must be in the range set by a prior [`UDM_SETRANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759963.aspx) or [`UDM_SETRANGE32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759968.aspx) message.

> I have ES_MULTILINE enabled on the UpDown control buddy. I needed this so I can detect Enter being pressed once the number is typed in

You don't need `ES_MULTILINE` for that.  A single-line edit control can detect <kbd>Enter</kbd> just fine.  Simply subclass the edit control to intercept the [`WM_CHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) message.  Its `wParam` will be 13 (`'\r'`) for an <kbd>Enter</kbd> press.

Comment: If the edit control is hosted in a dialog (or a window whose message loop calls [IsDialogMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx)), the subclassed control also needs to handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx) message and return `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`.

Comment: ES_WANTRETURN not enough? More likely he wants to set ~ES_WANTRETURN and pick up the return from the containing window.

Comment: @Ben: `ES_WANTRETURN` has no effect for single-line edit controls.

Comment: Any chance of seeing some code? I have ben trying different combinations of your suggestions and nothing has seemed to work. Thanks,

Comment: @Kenneth: Please update your question to show the code you have already tried that is not working for you.